# How to delete /remove blank row in an excel using VB script

Tags: excel, vbscript

I've script in which i will be comparing two excel data and will be writing the matching data in third excel. Script works perfectly and writes matching data to third excel. The issue is that it creates an empty row for mismatched data. Don't know how to delete the empty row or how can i prevent it from writing the empty data.

- In first Excel workbook `"C:\Excelone.xls"` ,the column A value are *1,2,3,4,5,6*
- In the second Excel workbook `"C:\Exceltwo.xls"` ,the column A value is *1,ab,3,ac,5,6*
- so after comparing, the output in third excel workobook (column A) is written as *1,Empty,3,Empty,5,6*

My required output is *1,3,5,6*

Please help me in solving the issue. Please find the below script

```
            Set myxl = createobject("excel.application")
            myxl.Workbooks.Open "C:\Excelone.xls"
            myxl.Application.Visible = true
            set mysheet = myxl.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
            Set myx2 = createobject("excel.application")
            myx2.Workbooks.Open "C:\Exceltwo.xls"
            myx2.Application.Visible = true
            set mysheet1 = myx2.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
            Set myx3 = createobject("excel.application")
            myx3.Workbooks.Open "C:\Excelthree.xls" 
            myx3.Application.Visible = true
            set mysheet3 = myx3.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
            row=0

            'With mysheet.UsedRange  
                For each search_data in mysheet.UsedRange
                row = row+1
                    For each search_data1 in mysheet1.UsedRange
                             If search_data=search_data1    Then  

                                    mysheet3.cells(row,1).value=search_data1

                                Exit For 
                             End If 
                     Next
                Next         
            'End With

            myxl.ActiveWorkbook.Save
            myxl.ActiveWorkbook.Close
            myxl.Application.Quit
            Set mysheet =nothing
            Set myxl = nothing
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try moving your counter (`row = row+1` ) inside the loop where there is a successful match, ie

```
For each search_data in mysheet.UsedRange   
'row = row+1            
   For each search_data1 in mysheet1.UsedRange
            If search_data=search_data1  Then  
                    row = row+1 
                    mysheet3.cells(row,1).value=search_data1
                    Exit For 
            End If 
   Next
Next
```

Comment: Thank you, it work's. I feel , how i'm bad at coding. So simple logic.